# Oracle Instance Client Light (odac 11) and character sets

Tags: oracle10g, oracle11g, oracleclient

I am trying to connect to oracle db without full installation of oracle client done on the machine.
I found this helpfull post [Using the new ODP.Net to access Oracle from C# with simple deployment](http://splinter.com.au/blog/?p=156) but when I try it, I am failed on the next exception:

[Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException **ORA-12737: Instant Client Light: unsupported server character set %s**    at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleErrorHelper(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, IntPtr opsErrCtx, OpoSqlValCtx* pOpoSqlValCtx, Object src, String procedure, Boolean bCheck)

at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleError(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, IntPtr opsErrCtx, Object src)
...

I tried to Google it up, but find nothing except "Do not use this character set" suggestions.

I occasionally I am working with NLS_LANG "american_america.US8PC437", but it can be different (client environment) character set.

Do you have any idea how can I extend light instance client with character sets resources?

**Thank you!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and google says the solution is 'some_big_oracle_package' installation, but I want to keep this away. So simply unpacked all dll files from ODAC112012Xcopy.zip 32bit (xcopy version ONLY). And it works! So I had to found the mysterious dll that pushed it to the next level. The one & only is

> oraociei11.dll

On my working-portable solution catalog I have .exe file and 4 dlls:

- oci.dll,
- Oracle.DataAccess.dll (version
  2.112.1.2),
- OraOps11w.dll
- oraociei11.dll

This stuff works on Win7 x86 & x64 and WinXP x86 (all the systems don't have Oracle or sth installed, pure copy & paste).
Notice that oraociei11.dll weighs 120MB! After compression ~40MB

Tell me if it works for you

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for your replay.
Actualy, I already did same thing you mentioned, but forgot to update this post.
Yes, it also works for me fine - I check it on Windows 2003 and windows 2008.

But - thanks once more for your replay!

Comment: please, why did you use the 32bit? I'm using this in a WCF/AppFabric cenario, and it's gotta be 64 bits, since it's running in Windows 2008 R2

Comment: Wow! Very old post but it worked fine for me. Can't believe Oracle hasn't done something to fix all of this...